# Failed passing parameters to a query in apollo

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a working query right here

```
 const getCicadaByUserIdQuery = gql`
 query($id:String){
  user(id:$id){
    id
    userName
    password
      cicadas {
        name
        id
        image
        long
        lat
        userid
      }
  }
}`
```

When passing a valid id of a user in localhost it will return data as expected.
What im trying to do is to pass parameter of a specific user base on the logged in user

```
export default compose(
 graphql(getCicadasQuery,{name:"getCicadasQuery"}),
 graphql(addCicadaMutation,{name:"addCicadaMutation"}),
 graphql(getCicadaByUserIdQuery,{
    name:"getCicadaByUserIdQuery",
    options: () => ({ variables: { id: getLoginUser().id } })

 }),
 graphql(getUsersQuery,{name:"getUsersQuery"}),
)(CicadaScoutScreen)
```

getLoginUser() is a simple function that returns data of the current login user.

And im calling this query by:

```
this.props.getCicadaByUserIdQuery
```

please help I cant seems to make it work

Answer (score 0):

If it works with localhost but not on your running server, perhaps it's something with how the `getLoginUser()` function is working.

You can console.log the output of that function to debug like so:

`graphql(getCicadaByUserIdQuery,{
    name:"getCicadaByUserIdQuery",
    options: () => {
      console.log(getLoginUser());
      return { variables: { id: getLoginUser().id } };
    }
 }),`

If it's working in localhost then it's probably not an issue with Apollo Client itself.

Comment: Thank you so much for commenting I just used a mutation for it and it works